# How to update catridges on OpenShift?

Tags: php, openshift

Hey guys its a very general question, but I need your help.
I already have an application at [Edited - Removed my site's link] which uses php 5.3
& now OpenShift has a new catridge called php 5.4..so how can I update the catridge without deleting my app?

Comment: in your control panel you can edit your application and add in the 5.4 cartridge then retire the 5.3 one after that its just a case of restarting the instance. should all be doable from your admin panel

Comment: No @Dave I tried to add a new catridge but the option of php 5.4 is not visible..though I can see the new mysql 5.5 & I'm using mysql 5.1..so forgive me for asking a second question, can i safely follow ur method to update mysql catridge??

Comment: not 100% sure on mysql you may have to install the 5.5 version and then migrate your data across (dump from one import to other) then shut 5.1 off.  If you can't see the 5.4 cartridge then RH may not have enabled it for everyone yet unless its a commandline install version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create a new application with the 5.4 cartridge and migrate your application to the new gears.  You currently can not remove and add a new version of a web cartridge. (you can try doing the migration with the rhc snapshot command)

Comment: hey @developercorey is the snapshot enough for mysql update as well..or do I have to take backup of database??

Comment: It should backup the database tables also, but a mysqldump would not hurt :)

Answer (score 0):

Hack for fast switching from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 and back.
This is not completely updates the cartridge and may works incorrect.

```
# Create backup configuration
mv ~/php/configuration ~/php/configuration-orig
cp -r ~/php/configuration-orig ~/php/configuration


# Switch PHP 5.3 -> PHP 5.4
sed -i 's|libphp5.so|libphp54-php5.so|' ~/php/configuration/etc/conf.d/php.conf
gear restart --cart php


# Switch PHP 5.4 -> PHP 5.3
sed -i 's|libphp54-php5.so|libphp5.so|' ~/php/configuration/etc/conf.d/php.conf
gear restart --cart php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but I'm still not comfortable with the windows command..I still use git gui for push/updating my app..