# Pip on Openshift

Tags: django, pip, openshift

This may be a very silly question, but I am currently hosting a Django project on Openshift, and I have run into a funny problem. Both locally and remotely I am using pip version 7.1.2, and I've just updated Django to version 1.9.1. However, latest version of Django I can install on Openshift is 1.9b1. Is there anything else I need to update in order for Openshift to have the latest list (package)?

EDIT: Is that because I'm using python 3.3 on openshift and 3.4 locally?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028364/how-do-i-update-django-on-openshift . And you may want to look into using a virtual environment locally. I don't think developing on a different version of python is a good idea.

Comment: I realized that yesterday. This was my issue: The Django 1.8 series is the last to support Python 3.2 and 3.3. I resorted to downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

This was my issue: The Django 1.8 series is the last to support Python 3.2 and 3.3.

I was using python 3.3 on Openshift.